# How to capture cookies from an Http Post that returns 302 instead of 200 in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, http

Currently if I do an http GET or POST and it returns 200 w/ a type of application/json or xml I can capture the cookies sent back using this method

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
  NSArray* returnedCookies = [NSHTTPCookie 
                  cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:[response allHeaderFields] 
                  forURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];

    [responseData setLength:0];
}
```

But when the request returns a 302 (redirect) how can I capture the cookies sent down to the client during the init request?  Currently I only get the cookies sent back after the 200 from the GET request following this redirect occurs

**Update**

What I found to be the final solution is below.  I needed the if statements to verify the resp was valid as this method is called a total of 3 times in my instance.  Once for the init request, then again for the 302 (the one I care about) and finally for the last GET request for the redirected url

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response {
  if (response != nil) {
    NSArray* cookies = [NSHTTPCookie 
                     cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields:[response allHeaderFields] 
                     forURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];

    if ([zzzz count] > 0) {
      //do something with cookies
    }
  }

  return request;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's delegate method on NSURLRequest that you can use for that:

[connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/connection%3awillSendRequest%3aredirectResponse%3a)

As you'll get the redirect response, you can extract the cookies from it.