# How to get the cookies from http post that returns 302 instead of 200 (android)

Tags: android, cookies, httpclient

I'm working with a login page that returns a 302 instead of 200 and I'm not able to get all the cookies using "((DefaultHttpClient) httpclient).getCookieStore()"

In objective-c I was able to work around this w/ the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709854/how-to-capture-cookies-from-an-http-post-that-returns-302-instead-of-200-in-objec)

Is it possible to get these cookies when a 302 is returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use the `getHeaders` method (see http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpMessage.html#getHeaders%28java.lang.String%29) on the `HttpResponse` returned by the `execute` method to access all `Set-Cookie` response headers. Those should contain all the cookies you want.

Comment: Sounds right: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/cookie/RFC2965Spec.html should give you a `List` of `Cookie`s you can use.